# How to open the actual source file from within the 'View Commit Details' view in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When selecting the 'View Commit Details' for a Git commit, Visual Studio 2022 opens a view with 3 panes. The current and preview commits of a changed file and a list of changed files. If I right-click on a file in the file list, it opens a temporary version of the file.

Is there a way to open the actual source file in a single action in that view?

Comment: It's crazy no one has been able to help on this. I am also experiencing the same annoyance of having to go back to the solution explorer to edit the file. Were you able to find a solution?